# Shopify Pipeline 7.1.1 Theme Add To Cart Button Open as POP UP

Tags: shopify, cart

We upgraded our Pipeline theme 4.3.3 to 7.1.1. When we click on Add To Cart Button it redirects to Cart page but we need to it to open cart as PopUp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- Go to your Shopify Admin.

2- Navigate to "Themes" and click on "Customize" for your Pipeline theme.

3- In the theme settings, locate the "Cart" section.

4- Within the "Cart" section, find the option named "Cart Type."

5- Change the "Cart Type" option to "Popup" or a similar value.

By following these steps, the "Add to Cart" button will now open the cart as a popup instead of redirecting to the cart page.